# Algoritmo que leia três números e exiba o resultado da soma dos dois primeiros e multiplicado pelo terceiro

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, algoritmo, while

Segue meu código abaixo, porem não retorna correto o resultado, se eu colocar como entrada 2, 2, 3 era para aparecer 12, porem aparece 6

```
public class Exercicio2 {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    int[] soma = new int[3];
    int numero1, numero2 = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while(i < 3){
        System.out.println("Informe um numero[" + i + "]");
        soma[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        soma[i] += soma[i];
        total = soma[i];
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesta linha

```
soma[i] += soma[i];
```

estás a multiplicar o que foi introduzido por 2. Ou seja, se introduziste 2 no índice 0 estás a fazer soma[0] = soma[0] + soma[0]

O que deves fazer é um ciclo onde apenas registas as entradas:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Informe um numero[" + i + "]");
    soma[i] = entrada.nextInt();
}
```

E logo a seguir fazes a conta:

```
total = (soma[0] + soma[1]) * soma[2];
```

Código final:

```
public class Exercicio2 {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] soma = new int[3];
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Informe um numero[" + i + "]");
        soma[i] = entrada.nextInt();
    }
    total = (soma[0] + soma[1]) * soma[2];
    System.out.println(total);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Só teria que fazer a verificação das etapas realizadas pelo `while`, recebeu o primeiro número, fez incremento na variável `i`, e contém o valor `1` é porque já recebeu o primeiro e o segundo número, então faz a soma, se contém o valor `2` é porque recebeu o terceiro então faz a multiplicação.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        // Alterei o nome da variavel, soma para numeros.
        int[] numeros = new int[3];
        // Criei outra variavel int com nome soma.
        int soma = 0;
        // int numero1, numero2 = 0; -> Não tem utilidade
        int total = 0;
        while(i < 3){
            System.out.println("Informe um numero[" + i + "]");
            numeros[i] = entrada.nextInt();
            // Verifica se já recebeu o primeiro numero, então faz a soma do primeiro com o segundo
            if (i == 1) {
                soma = numeros[0] + numeros[1];
            }
            // Ultima etapa, multiplica pelo terceiro.
            if (i == 2) {
                total = soma * numeros[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
```